# codeigniter where to process sql result?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
class SelectedModel extends CI_Model {

    var $title   = 'SelectedModel';
    var $content = 'get top n articles';
    var $date    = '23.2.2011';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getTopArticles()
    {
       $result = $this->db->query('select top 5 article from articles;');
       if( ! $result->num_rows() > 0 )
           die('There are no articles in db.');

       return $result;
    }
}


class Front extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper(array('text', 'html'));
        $this->load->model('SelectedModel');

        // controller process data and validate it
        $top_articles = $this->SelectedModel->getTopArticles();
        foreach($top_articles->result() as $item)
        {
            $item->desc = character_limiter($item->desc, 75);
            if( strlen($item->image) == 0 )
                $item->desc = '/images/default.png'; 
        }


        $data['title'] = 'title';
        $data['random_articles'] = $top_articles;
        $this->load->view('front', $data);
    }
}
```

Front View:

```
php foreach($random_articles->result() as $item):
    php echo $item->desc
    php echo br() . $item->image
php endforeach;
```

I'm wondering if my knowledge of MVC is correct. In controller I process data, prepare them to show them in view. In view there is room only for html/css code and echo $var..
Model function is to get data.

Are there any other approaches to process data. Is my way ok?

Optimization issue:
$top_articles = $this->SelectedModel->getTopArticles();
I don't know exactly how php manages this line. I'm just asking if $top_articles is a copy of getTopArticles, so I use twice as many memory if i would use in my view:

Front View:

```
php foreach($random_articles->result() as $item):
    php echo character_limiter($item->desc, 75)
    php echo br() . if( strlen($item->image) == 0 ) echo images/default.png''; else echo $item->image;
php endforeach;
```

But with this approach I don't use MVC(using character_limit, .... in view).

Comment: You have a lot of code and several statements about it. But I can't seem to determine what you are actually asking about?

Comment: I am asking about in which controller, model, view do you process/validate data. As I got the answer you process/validate data in controller and pass it to view. You generate data in a model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the idea down. The MVC approach doesn't always mean its better optimized.

Generating data in a model, passing it to the controller, and then to the view is the correct way to do this, even though it would seem as though you could just do it all from the view with just as many lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main question besides optimization, is that by MVC approach you proces/validate data in controller not in view or model. In view you just simply show data. In controller you can do things like if( isset($data)) .. if( strcmp($data,"something).... In view the only thing you do despite programming language is echo/print/show(pseudo code) data.

Comment: For processing/validating data, you should be doing most of this in your controller. Always pass xss/db cleaned data to model parameters. If you are using any form helpers, the form validation would be done in the controller too. A model should be able to validate certain types of data, but i guess this depends on what exactly the validation process was doing.